# How to Do Enter For Space in array of char in c++?

Tags: c++

My code is here:

```
char s[50];

cin.get(s,50);

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    if (s[i] = ' ')
    {
        //Suppose to do Enter
    }

}
cout << s << endl;
```

### Input:

```
Welcome to c++
```

### Expected Output :

```
Welcome
to
c++
```

Comment: Assignment is `=`, equality-comparison  is `==`.

Comment: Whats different between input and output?

Comment: And what's stopping you from simply assigning a newline when you have a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
char s[50];
cin.get(s,50);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    if (s[i] == ' '){
      s[i]='\n';  //Suppose to do Enter
      }
    }
cout << s << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do know about checking if something is of a certain value (the`if` statement and the equality operator `==`)?

Do do know how to assign a value to a variable?

Then you already know how to solve your problem!

Pseudo code:

```
if (A == SomeValue)
    A = SomeOtherValue;
```